# How to use existing websocket connection to another websocket request in jmeter?

Tags: websocket, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

How to use existing websocket connection to another websocket request in jmeter?

When I tried to use existing connect then as result it show me an error "Sampler configured for using existing connection, but there is no connection" . Please refer attached screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwZ5i.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoMrz.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using 2 different WebSocket Samplers implementations:

1. [JMeter-WebSocketSampler](https://github.com/fshutdown/JMeter-WebSocketSampler)
2. and [JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/)

Your `WebSocket Single Write Sampler`:

1. Doesn't know anything about the connection established by the `WebSocket Sampler`
2. The `WebSocket Sampler` closes the connection after receiving the response

So if you want to continue with the `WebSocket Single Write Sampler` you need to:

1. Use `WebSocket Open Connection` sampler to establish the connection:

   [image]
2. In the `WebSocket Single Write Sampler` tick `use existing connection box`

   [image]

More information: [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide)

If you want to continue with the `WebSocket Sampler` - tick `Streaming connection` box:

[image]

and remove the  `WebSocket Single Write Sampler` and friends from the Test Plan